# How to print a numpy array as a string of the format (1 2) (3 4) (5 6)?

Tags: python, string, numpy, format

I have a numpy array such as follows:

```
[[181  2]
 [  3 45]
 [  5  6]]
```

However, I'm required to print it as this new format:

```
(181 2) (3 45) (5 6)
```

I have tried:

```
' '.join(map(str, my_arr)).replace('[','(').replace(']',')')
```

However, due to the whitespace in the original numpy array, the map includes this whitespace so that my result is:

```
(181  2) (  3 45) (  5  6)
```

Which includes the original whitespace. Unfortunately, this is an unacceptable format for my purposes, but I cannot figure out a solution.

I have also tried flattening the array first and then converting it to a string of numbers of the following format:

```
181 2 3 45 5 6
```

But, from here I wouldn't know how to insert ( and ) characters for every pair of numbers to get the required format above?

Comment: "Unfortunately, this is an unacceptable format for my purposes." May I ask what your purposes are to require a strict string formatting for numeric data?

Comment: A process down the line and out of my hands takes only this format. The array is the end result of quite a lot of linear algebra done in numpy, so I am left at the end with an array in the wrong format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution. But you should consider whether you really need to perform this kind of manipulation of numeric data.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[181,  2],
                [  3, 45],
                [  5,  6]])

print(''.join('('+' '.join(map(str, i))+') ' for i in arr))

# (181 2) (3 45) (5 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
' '.join(map(lambda row : '(' + ' '.join(map(str, row)) + ')', my_arr))
```

Comment: try adding some explanations to the OP (and others with similar questions) about why this works

Answer (score 0):

One more for the collection:

```
>>> from itertools import starmap
>>> a = np.arange(6).reshape(3, 2)
>>> ' '.join(starmap(' '.join(a.shape[1] * ['{}']).join('()').format, a))
'(0 1) (2 3) (4 5)'
```